# How to get json stored data on radio button click

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm beginner in javascript and php. I'm passing json data on radio button click to js and then particular radio selection I want to get it and display on html table

```
$return_arr=array();
$row_array['firstName']= $row['firstName'];
$row_array['lastName']= $row['lastName'];
$row_array['mobiePhoneNumber']= $row['mobiePhoneNumber'];
$row_array['officePhoneNumber']= $row['officePhoneNumber'];

// here push data into json array
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

$(".radioBtn").click(function(event){
     e.preventDefault();
     // using data attribute getting data of radio button click (json data)
     sendAjaxRequest(($(this).data("jsondata")));
});

function sendAjaxRequest(element,urlToSend)
{
  // here element has got whole json data but not able to get one by one data
  // I have used JSON.parse(element); but page is not working
  var jsondata = element; 

  alert(jsondata.firstName);   

  //var jsonDataa = $.parse(jsondata);
  alert(jsondata["firstName"]);
}
```

From HTML passing radio selected whole json data

```
<input type="radio" id="radioBtn" class="radioBtn" name="radioBtn"
       data-jsondata=<?php echo json_encode($return_arr)?>>
```

[image]

Update::
   these code is working but because of some reason it was not working ie. radio button is inside foreach loop (not getting whole data from d) and the **data-jsondata** data attribute is not containing proper format that's why it was not working otherwise its working thanks everyone!! happy coding

Comment: json data may contain spaces, dont forget to add brackets to the PHP tags `data-jsondata="<?php echo json_encode($return_arr)?>"`

Comment: ..it'll also contain quotes, so you better escape them before.

Comment: Shouldn't he be parsing the JSON value too?

Comment: I recommend _NOT_ to save data like that in an html-element. Better have a simple js-var.

Comment: thanks to you all for giving ur valuable time..

Comment: hey gys!! I have attached these screent shot can you go through and give piece of clue so that i can further implement .. have got stuck for long day 
thanx

Comment: @@jeff 
I recommend NOT to save data like that in an html-element. Better have a simple js-var
can you tell brief abt  js-var ... coz using this strategy not able to pass whole data string size is limitted and i'm having bunch of data so i'v to follow another one so let me know what you were saying ??

Comment: I have solved these

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
// Suppose Your JSON data is {"name":"abcd","age":"22"}  from PHP
<input type="radio" onclick="call(this)" data-jsondata='{"name":"abcd","age":"22"}' /> abc


function call(obj){
   var data = obj.getAttribute("data-jsondata");
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(data.name);
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/px7zxum2/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: call is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://url/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=23:813:593

Comment: is there any different way to show that corresponding data right side **div** after getting whole data from **db** and show right div on radio click

Comment: i have attached screet shot pls help  i have got stuck for log time @Divesh Oswal

Comment: Looks like parsing issue, could you please tell what JSON data is coming [echo ...]

Comment: [{"contactsId":"690967","firstName":"atul","lastName":"sharma","mobiePhoneNumber":"987484748847","officePhoneNumber":"3837388373","email":"pandey@gmail.com","notes":"hello atul, meet me on wednesday.","address":"zone-2","address2":"khursipar","city":"bhilai","state":"cg","zip":"490011","website":"www.pandey.com","title":"engineer","companyName":"pandeyService","customfield1":"pandey field1","customfield2":"pandey field2","customfiel3":"pandey field3"}]

Comment: Problem in json data. Check this in `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/` . It saying invalid json data. Error is at line ' "city"‌​ : "bhilai", ' .   When I removed it and entered manually it says valid data. I don't know why error is coming at that line.

Comment: Copy paste your JSON data in `http://jsonlint.com/`  , You will see some other characters also

Comment: ohhk
bt i put my current json data that is very long and says **valid data**

Comment: it was just silly mistake not getting whole data from json i'v put push json inside loop ,  for some condition jsondata variable is not getting whole data and i'm passing on radio click listener which (data-jsondata) has not proper formatted so that its not able to parse  .... thanks every one  and specially you sir @@Divesh Oswal

Answer (score 0):

The data-jsondata should be wrapped in quotes

```
data-jsondata="<?php echo json_encode($return_arr)?>"
```

then, in sendAjaxRequest, be sure to use JSON.parse, as "element" at this place is a string

EDIT: according to https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 the JQuery's data() does the JSON parsing for you already, so you don't have to use JSON.parse() anyway

Comment: Ok, two things.. firstly, you have to wrap the jsondata in ', not ", my bad (json will have " in it which causes problems)

Comment: secondly, in your click(), event is named "event" not "e", so e.preventdefault will not work
See https://jsfiddle.net/dbs70u3c/
your example, without the php part, working